# how to get the number of a specific element in every row of a big dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a big `data.frame` composed of `239` objects and `546639` variables. The elements of the `data.frame` include `A`, `B`, or `0`. Now I want to know the number of every element in every row. The following is part of the `data.frame`.

```
1 rs22233… B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B    
2 rs38622… B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     A     B     A    
3 rs13933… B     B     A     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B    
4 rs38637… B     B     A     A     A     B     B     B     A     B     A    
5 rs12554… B     B     B     B     A     B     A     B     B     B     B    
6 rs41105… A     A     A     A     B     A     B     A     A     A     B
```

Comment: Why not use `plink` to calculate the minor allele frequency, then multiply it by the sample size? https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` to count by rows using `table`:

```
apply(df[-c(1,2)],1,table)
# [[1]]
# 
# B 
# 11 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# A B 
# 2 9 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
# A  B 
# 1 10 
# 
# [[4]]
# 
# A B 
# 5 6 
# 
# [[5]]
# 
# A B 
# 2 9 
# 
# [[6]]
# 
# A B 
# 8 3
```

Comment: @张力三 glad you were able to get an answer to your question. When this happens, you should assign the answer checkmark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1:

Using `table` (thanks to @thelatemail):

```
table(factor(unlist(df[-1]), levels = c("A", "B", "0")), row(df[-1]))        
#    1  2  3  4  5  6
# A  0  2  1  5  2  8
# B 11  9 10  6  9  3
# 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Or (slower):

```
sapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(x)
    table(factor(unlist(x[, -1]), levels = c("A", "B", "0"))))
#   1 2  3 4 5 6
#A  0 2  1 5 2 8
#B 11 9 10 6 9 3
#0  0 0  0 0 0 0
```

Explanation: `factor(..., levels = c("A", "B", "0"))` ensures that `table` will always report counts for the same three `factor` levels, which you can then store in a `matrix`.

### Method 2:

Using `rle`:

```
lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), function(x)
    as.data.frame(unclass(rle(as.character(sort(unlist(x[, -1])))))))
#$`1`
#  lengths values
#1      11      B
#
#$`2`
#  lengths values
#1       2      A
#2       9      B
#
#$`3`
#  lengths values
#1       1      A
#2      10      B
#
#$`4`
#  lengths values
#1       5      A
#2       6      B
#
#$`5`
#  lengths values
#1       2      A
#2       9      B
#
#$`6`
#  lengths values
#1       8      A
#2       3      B
```

### Method 3:

Using `tidyr::gather` and `dplyr::count`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -V2) %>%
    count(V2, val)
## A tibble: 11 x 3
#V2       val       n
#<fct>    <chr> <int>
#1 rs12554… A         2
#2 rs12554… B         9
#3 rs13933… A         1
#4 rs13933… B        10
#5 rs22233… B        11
#6 rs38622… A         2
#7 rs38622… B         9
#8 rs38637… A         5
#9 rs38637… B         6
#10 rs41105… A         8
#11 rs41105… B         3
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "1 rs22233… B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B    
2 rs38622… B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     A     B     A    
3 rs13933… B     B     A     B     B     B     B     B     B     B     B    
4 rs38637… B     B     A     A     A     B     B     B     A     B     A    
5 rs12554… B     B     B     B     A     B     A     B     B     B     B    
6 rs41105… A     A     A     A     B     A     B     A     A     A     B   ", row.names = 1)
```

Comment: You probably want to avoid having to run `table` for every row - you could table a long vector representing the whole data.frame against `row(df[-1])` potentially (not tested)

Comment: @thelatemail Not sure; you'll have to operate on the rows in one way or the other. I haven't done any benchmarking, so I don't know how `table` will scale with larger datasets. BTW, I've also added 2 additional methods (using `rle` and a `dplyr`/`tidyr` solution).

Comment: `table(factor(unlist(df[-1]), levels=c("A","B","0")), row(df[-1]))` for instance is about 16x faster than the `sapply` version.  The `dplyr` version is considerably faster again but gives a different output obviously.

Comment: @thelatemail Ah yes, I clearly misunderstood what you hinted at in your earlier comment. `table(factor(unlist(df[-1]), levels=c("A","B","0")), row(df[-1]))` seems to be the most concise and efficient solution (in base R).

Comment: @thelatemail As before, I'll add this if you don't mind.

Comment: As always, go for it :-D

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, V3:V13) %>% 
  group_by(V2) %>% 
  count(value) %>% 
  spread(value, n)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   V2 [6]
  V2           A     B
  <fct>    <int> <int>
1 rs12554…     2     9
2 rs13933…     1    10
3 rs22233…    NA    11
4 rs38622…     2     9
5 rs38637…     5     6
6 rs41105…     8     3
```